# MongoDb update in to array

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I need you to do a kind of if else before you run the push.
If the user is in the array, I need you to delete it
and if it's not there I'll add it. Is there a function that gets this?. Thanks for the help.

```
var publicationId = req.params.id;
Publication.updateOne({ _id: publicationId }, { $push: { like:  req.user.sub  } }, (err) => {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error in the request' });
    return res.status(200).send({
        messages: req.user.sub
    })
});
```

Comment: can you be more specific and also add how your document should look like before and after updating it

Comment: If I'm making an array of likes in a post, what I want to achieve is that when a request is made if I update the array (so far it is updated but the information is overlapped and it only has one value) and before I put it in I check if that id exists in the array and if it exists I delete it. Thank you for responding

Comment: you can use "$elemMatch" on query and "$" operator to update the specific index. kindly see this reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: Okay, can you also add how your like array looks like? Basically you will have to first fetch the publication and then check if the `like` array contains the thing you're looking for and then add it if it isn't present and then finally save it. Are you using mongoose?

Comment: {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ea81398ffecc219b847dcb8"),
    "like" : [],
    "text" : "Hello",
    "file" : "null",
    "user" : ObjectId("5ea410f6940b4c1dc5c9fd83"),
    "location" : "null",
    "__v" : 0
}

Comment: Yes I'm using mongoose, My only problem is how can I make an if else within the update to delete or add

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem

```
Publication.findOne({ like: { $in: [req.user.sub] }, _id: publicationId }, function name(err, result) {
    if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error in the request' });
    if (!result) {
        Publication.updateOne({ _id: publicationId }, { $push: { like: req.user.sub } }, (err) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error in the request' });
            return res.status(200).send({
                messages: req.user.sub
            })
        });
    } else {
        Publication.updateOne({ _id: publicationId }, { $pull: { like: req.user.sub } }, (err) => {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error in the request' });
            return res.status(200).send({
                messages: "deleted"
            })
        });
    }
});
```